# Azure data factory schema drift

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

I'm working on a solution where i need to allow schema drift without recreating table. I have 50 files with tb's of data in azure data lake and i need to load the data in azure sql db. My current schema has 50 columns but i expect schema to change and more columns added in future. Mapping data flow allows schema drift but recreates table and drops data if modify time filter is applied. Is there a way to implement a solution to manage schema drift without dropping table data and just alter the table with new schema.

Comment: You can create external table in that way data won't be dropped

Comment: External table or execute a stored proc activity or data flow with a pre-processing script in the SQL Sink that alters the table first. Then execute your data flow to load the data.

Comment: but problem lies is how to find if schema changed for files in azure data lake gen2 when using schema drift